# Abstract class or an interface : JAVA?

Tags: java

I have one common method which i need to use in several classes with just a single call from the calling class.
So what i see is i can call it in two ways.

```
public abstract class TestAbstractClass {
    void commonMethod(){
        System.out.println("Calling common method : TestAbstractClass");
    }
}
```

calling class:

```
public class RunApplication extends TestAbstractClass{

    public void testMethod(){
        commonMethod();
    }
}
```

[OR]

Using Java 8 feature of default method in interface.

```
public interface TestInterface {
    default void commonMethod(){
        System.out.println("Calling common method : TestInterface");
    }
}
```

calling class:

```
public class RunApplication implements TestInterface{

    public void testMethod(){
        commonMethod();
    }
}
```

They both works fine for me,
But what is better approach, an abstract class with non-abstract method OR
Interface with default method.

Comment: There are arguments to support both. Best is to look at the differences. For instance, if you ever want the child class to inherit another class, extending an abstract class is not what you want to do.

Comment: Such questions do not make sense on stack overflow - the answers really depend on the concrete problem you have to solve. There is no generic "this or that is better" here.

Comment: The question is also if this one method is so heavily intertwined with the rest of the classes that it should be in an interface or abstract class. Maybe it should be a static method instead, or it should be in a separate class from which you create fields in the other classes.

Comment: Interface will allow you to not block the inheritance for your class. For example, if your class must become a child, it will be allowed, which is not the case if it already inherits another class.

Comment: It's all depending upon your requirement but as i think if you are extending in this case then you are taking one property from child class as after that child class will not be able to extend any other class but in the case of interface you have the option to extend any other class as well as use the implementation defined in the interface using default keyword

Comment: Interfaces are in general simpler and can have multiple inheritance. Where possible use an interface.

Comment: Thanks to all for all your efforts and suggestions, perhaps for my answer i have gone through java 8 docs on interface and understand it is designed for different purpose. And for my requirement abstract class suits best. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

> Abstract class or an interface

If I were you I will judge the appropriateness by checking whether all those classes are ***related*** or not.

Generally, I will use interface if the classes which implements it have little or not relation at all and they just happened to share certain behaviour which can be exposed by the method from the interface.

I will use ***abstraction*** when the classes are a subset of the other.

**Example:**

Using bird and plane as an example. Birds and planes both flies. But other than that, they isn't related at all. You will naturally want to implement an interface instead of using abstract class because neither planes are birds and neither birds are planes.

```
class Bird implements Flyable
{
    @Override
    public void fly(){

    }
}

class Plane implements Flyable
{
    @Override
    public void fly(){

    }
}
```

---

*Another issue to consider is **multiple inheritance**. In Java, multiple inheritance of a class is not allowed. Hence if you use abstraction, your sub-class won't be able to extends to another class.*

*If your class implements an interface, it can always implements another interface or extends to one other class.*

Answer (score 1):

This will be an opinionated thread.

My take here is that you should go with the `abstract` class: it provides common functionality for its descendants.

The default methods in Java 8 interfaces *can* do that as well, but they are designed for something slightly different:

> Default methods enable you to add new functionality to the interfaces of your libraries and ensure binary compatibility with code written for older versions of those interfaces.

(From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)).

In other words, adding a default method to an interface allows you to enrich the interface without breaking inheritance.

Also note that using Java 8's `default` interface method idioms limits your backwards compatibility, although this is likely a non-issue here (otherwise I guess you wouldn't be juggling with the two methodologies in the first place).

Ultimately it all boils down to the desired kind of abstraction in your common ancestor, and how you want it derived in the children.

**Note**

I am not elaborating on the "abstract class vs interface" typical dichotomy here, as it is assumed you know the pros and cons.

Comment: Well, but you can implement the interface *and* subclass from another class. This is not if you already subclass from an abstract class... :)

Comment: @hfhc2 that pertains to the standard and well-known abstract class vs interface dichotomy. I'm assuming the OP knows that already.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance in any of its forms is designed to be used with polymorphism.

If you have a common method, don't just push it level up to superclass but  think of using separate class to wrap it there. This way you can later refactor code to use strategy design pattern in case of any fluctuations in common method.